# Ansible only run when subelement of variable exists

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have some variables defined like this:

```
x_php_versions_installed:
  php70:
    - php70-curl
    - php70-xml
    - php70-xmlrpc
    - php70-zip
    - pecl-memcached
  php71:
    - php71-curl
    - php71-xml
    - php71-xmlrpc
    - php71-zip
  php72:
    - php72-curl
    - php72-xml
    - php72-xmlrpc
    - php72-zip
    - pecl-memcached
```

And I would like to check all of the vars (php70, php71, php72 and so on) has this variable: pecl-memcached and if one has, then run a command. My playbook looks like this:

```
- name: memcached pecl install
  pear:
    executable: '/usr/local/{{ item }}/bin/pecl'
    name: 'pecl/memcached'
    state: 'latest'
  with_items: '{{ x_php_versions_installed | list }}'
  when: 'item.pecl-memcached is defined'
```

this should call the `/usr/local/php70/bin/pecl` and `/usr/local/php72/bin/pecl` binary to install memcached. As soon as I remove the `when` condition, it works very well, but it will call every variable inside `x_php_versions_installed` not only where pecl-memcached is defined. So I need to fix the `when` condition in this case, but all of my tries are gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `when` to check a list properly, you'll have to use the test operator [`in`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#in) of Jinja:

```yaml
- name: memcached pecl install
  pear:
    executable: '/usr/local/{{ item }}/bin/pecl'
    name: 'pecl/memcached'
    state: 'latest'
  with_items: '{{ x_php_versions_installed | list }}'
  when: "'pecl-memcached' in x_php_versions_installed[item]"
```

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    x_php_versions_installed:
      php70:
        - php70-curl
        - php70-xml
        - php70-xmlrpc
        - php70-zip
        - pecl-memcached
      php71:
        - php71-curl
        - php71-xml
        - php71-xmlrpc
        - php71-zip
      php72:
        - php72-curl
        - php72-xml
        - php72-xmlrpc
        - php72-zip
        - pecl-memcached

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ x_php_versions_installed | list }}"
      when: "'pecl-memcached' in x_php_versions_installed[item]"
```

The recap would be:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=php70) => {
    "msg": "php70"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=php71) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=php72) => {
    "msg": "php72"
}
```

---

Your subelement is a list not a dictionary, so accessing an element key like your are trying here, i.e.:

```yaml
when: "x_php_versions_installed[item]['pecl-memcached'] is defined"
```

would work on a dictionary like this one:

```yaml
x_php_versions_installed:
  php70:
    php70-curl:
    php70-xml:
    php70-xmlrpc:
    php70-zip:
    pecl-memcached:
# same goes for the other versions of PHP
```

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    x_php_versions_installed:
      php70:
        php70-curl:
        php70-xml:
        php70-xmlrpc:
        php70-zip:
        pecl-memcached:
      php71:
        php71-curl:
        php71-xml:
        php71-xmlrpc:
        php71-zip:
      php72:
        php72-curl:
        php72-xml:
        php72-xmlrpc:
        php72-zip:
        pecl-memcached:

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ x_php_versions_installed | list }}"
      when: "x_php_versions_installed[item]['pecl-memcached'] is defined"
```

The recap would be:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=php70) => {
    "msg": "php70"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=php71) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=php72) => {
    "msg": "php72"
}
```

Comment: This works for me fine, and gladly, I also don't need to modify the dict (`:` after each phpXY element) Without them it's working.

Comment: yup, there is the two flavour, one staying with the `when` as you wrote it, that needs a dictionary, then other that works on your list